# Запрос на удаление используя обычный SQl

Tags: laravel

Парни приветсвую, подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить мой запрос, чтобы он удалил полученные записи-
$mes = DB::select("SELECT d.id FROM dialogs d LEFT JOIN messages m ON LEAST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = LEAST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) AND GREATEST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = GREATEST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) WHERE m.dialog_id IS NULL");

пробовал на концовку подставлять ->delete()   но не срабатывает. думаю потому, что там массив на выходе из айдишек.   скрин ниже ДД-шки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрос на удаление начинать со слова SELECT? Смотреть больно

Comment: DB::delete   я тоже пробовал)

Comment: cуть была в том, что следующей строкой после выборки дать команду типа- $mes->delete();     но так не работает((

Answer (score 0):

вот так заработало-

```
$mes = DB::select("SELECT d.id FROM dialogs d LEFT JOIN messages m ON LEAST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = LEAST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) AND GREATEST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = GREATEST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) WHERE m.dialog_id IS NULL");
```

$ids_to_delete = implode(', ', array_column($mes, 'id'));
$del = DB::delete("DELETE FROM dialogs WHERE id IN ($ids_to_delete)");